# Is it possible to open ViewController from background mode or when app is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, pushkit

I am trying to open `ViewController` on received push notification. I am doing it like this

```swift
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
    guard let aps = payload.dictionaryPayload[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary else {
        return
    }
    startCustomCallController(apnData: app)
}

func startCustomCallController(apnData: NSDictionary) {
    let storyBord = UIStoryboard(name: "PrivateUi", bundle: nil)
    guard let controller = storyBord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewIncomingCallViewController") as? NewIncomingCallViewController else{
        print("Error instantiating view controller")
        return
    }
    controller.apnData = apnData
    guard let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        print("appdelegate is missing")
        return
    }
    UIView.transition(with: appdelegate.window!, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = controller
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

It is working when app is open (In Foreground) But not working when is in background or killed.
Is it not possible or do I need to make some changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to start `ViewController` from background model I think. If you want to open `viewcontroller` for call related task batter to use [callkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

````
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
    // report new incoming call
}```
````